Customize registration in .NET8 Identity
I'm trying to learn .NET8 and I'm building my first API. In my project I'm using Identity.EntityFrameworkCore to be able to handle user related stuff. I created my custom User class in order to add a few properties for the user, here is my class.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Blog.Models.Entities
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public byte[]? ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Article>? blogs { get; set; }
    }
}


I did the required configuration and I got access to the default endpoints /login, /register... which is perfect, but when I try to register a user, I can only provide the email and passowrd in my request body but I want to be able to provide the other properties I created in my custom User class and to do that I created my custom register endpoint
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterUserDto input)
{
    var user = new User()
    {
        FirstName = input.FirstName,
        LastName = input.LastName,
        BirthDate = input.BirthDate,
        Email = input.Email,
        UserName = input.UserName,
    };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, input.PasswordHash);
    string message = string.Empty;
    if (result.Succeeded) 
        return Ok("User created successfully");
    return BadRequest("Error occured");
}

And I got the expected result. However my problem is that now, I do have 2 register endpoints, the one provided by Identity and the one I created. I can remove
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

and
app.MapIdentityApi<User>();

from Program.cs,
but that will also get rid of the other endpoints such as /login, /refresh, /forgotPassword... which I want to keep.
And so my question is, is it possible to only get rid of the default register method while keeping the others?

Can you share the register endpoint generated by Identity? You should be able to add your other properties

Unfortunately, it is not possible to override/edit the built-in .NET Identity API endpoints.
Although they are great for default implementations of Web API security using the Identity Framework they are not extensible.
I found this answer to another question, it explains exactly what you need to implement your own endpoints.
Hope this helps!
